# Tight Runtime Bound for loop

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

Can someone help me with finding the tight runtime bound for this loop:

```
for(c4=0, i=1; i<=n; i = 2*i)
   for(j=1; j<= i; j++)
       c4++;
```

I am not sure what to do with the 2*i in the outer loop, I think that the inner loop is something like O(i-1)/1 and in terms of n would be O(n-1) because of the while i<=n.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer loop will run `log(N)` times. For each outer loop, the inner loop will run `i` times. And `i` goes from 1, , 2, 4, 8, 16, ..., log(N).

So the total is about 2^(log(N)) - 1, it is O(N)